# Determine all rational numbers $x$ with this property

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number. A rational number $x$, with $0 < x < 1$, is written in lowest terms. The rational number obtained from $x$ by adding $p$ to both the numerator and denominator differs from $x$ by $\dfrac{1}{p^2}$. Determine all rational numbers $x$ with this property.

**Attempt:**

We have $x = \dfrac{a}{b}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $a<b, \gcd(a,b) = 1$. Then by the condition of the question, $\dfrac{a+p}{b+p}-\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{1}{p^2}$.

The answer is $(a,b) = (p^2-p-1,p^2)$ and $(a,b) = (1,2)$ which is obtained using simple divisibility combined with algebra, but I don't see how to get that from what I have.

Answer (score 3):

You have $\frac{a+p}{b+p}-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{p(b-a)}{b(b+p)}$. So you require $b(b+p)=(b-a)p^3$. Now $p$ divides $b$ iff it divides $b+p$, so it must divide both. There are now two cases to consider: (1) $p^2$ divides $b$, and (2) $p^2$ divides $b+p$.

(1) Put $b=kp^2$. We have $k(kp+1)=b-a=kp^2-a$, so $k$ must also divide $a$. But $a,b$ have no common factors, so $k=1$ and we have $(p+1)=p^2-a$, or $a=p^2-p-1$. It is easy to check that gives a solution for any prime $p$.

(2) Put $b+p=kp^2$. We have $k(kp-1)=b-a$. But $b=p(kp-1)$, so $kp-1$ divides $a$ and $b$. Since $a,b$ are coprime, we must have $p=2,k=1$ and hence $b=2,a=1$.

Comment: Why did you state "Now $p$ divides $b$ if and only if it divides $b+p$, so it must divide both" and instead do it with $p^2$? Couldn't you have done it with $p$?

Comment: We know that $p^3$ divides $b(b+p)$. So $p$ must divide either or both of $b,b+p$. But if it divides one it divides the other, so it must divide both.

Comment: Where did you use that fact?

Comment: In coming up with the two cases (1),(2).  If we had had $p^3$ divides $b(b+p+1)$ for example, then the cases would have been different: either $p^3$ divides $b$ or $p^3$ divides $b+p+1$.

Comment: I get your two cases. I don't see why it was necessary to mention  "Now $p$ divides $b$ if and only if it divides $b+p$, so it must divide both".

Comment: Did you need to mention it?

Comment: This exchange is leading nowhere. I still think it was helpful to mention it. You can cut any given line out of a proof. The question is whether that is helpful or unhelpful for the average reader. In my view, it is helpful to put that line in. You disagree.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the requested difference is unsigned, so we actually want $\frac{a + p}{b + p} - \frac{a}{b} = \pm \frac{1}{p^2}$.  But we can eliminate the negative option because $x < 1$, so $a < b$, and $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a + p}{b + p}$.

Clearing the denominators, we get $bp^2(a + p) - ap^2(b + p) = b(b+p)$.

Thus, $(b - a)p^3 = b(b + p)$.

$a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so $b$ and $(b - a)$ must be relatively prime.

Thus, $b | p^3$, which gives us $b = 1, p, p^2,$ or $p^3$.

$0 < a < b$, and $a$ and $b$ are integers, so $b \ne 1$.

If $b = p$, then we get $(p - a)p^3 = p(2p)$, so $(p - a)p = 2$.  The only prime $p$ dividing $2$ is $2$, so we get $b = p = 2$ and $a = 1$.

If $b = p^2$, then we get $(p^2 - a)p^3 = p^2(p^2 + p)$, so $p^2 - a = p + 1$.  Thus, $a = p^2 - p - 1$.

If $b = p^3$, then we get $(p^3 - a)p^3 = p^3(p^3 + p)$, so $p^3 - a = p^3 + p$.  This is impossible, as $a > 0$ and $p > 0$.

Therefore, the two solutions are $(a, b) = (1, 2)$ and $(a, b) = (p^2 - p - 1, p)$, as expected.